# How to send data to the old phone over COM port?

Tags: serial-port, reverse-engineering

I have a pretty old feature phone that I want to reverse engineer and alter firmware on it. I managed to establish serial connection with it but the serial port monitor waits on an instruction `IOCTL_SERIAL_WAIT_ON_MASK`
[image]

Any message I send to it is echoed back. After I send 8 packets in a row, it responds me with this message "NO AT moudle,register the  function (g_uat_stran_callbck)! Reference usb_uart_init()"

I have literally no clue what is going on. My goal is to download firmware and then upload it back

Comment: Maybe this documentation can help you: https://sisoog.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/Quectel_BC66_AT_Commands_Manual_V1.0.pdf